# Track in kml-file don't show in map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I trace my sailing days with a garmin gps, transfer it with mapsource to google earth and put the extracted kml-file to my website.

Since a few days I don't see the map. After trying several things I see the map again. It seemed that I must initalize with a lat/long. But I don't see the track.

Here the Link to a Example-Track: [Sample Track](http://www.skippercharly.de/Segeln/Track2.html)

Have someone any idea?

Sincerly
Charly

Answer (score 0):

You have a javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: GGeoXml is not defined Track2.html:23
```

You are including the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

But using [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1) constructs:

```
var kml = new GGeoXml("http://www.skippercharly.de/2013/Tracks/Balearen/2013-09-29.kml");
map.addOverlay(kml)
```

The correct v3 construct ([KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions)) doesn't have a "URL" option (javascript is case sensitive), the option is "url":

```
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({URL: 'http://www.skippercharly.de/2013/Tracks/Balearen/2013-09-29.kml'});
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

should be:

```
 var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: 'http://www.skippercharly.de/2013/Tracks/Balearen/2013-09-29.kml'});
 ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```